# Best resources for HPC with mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, reference-request

I am quite good with Mathematica and functional programming in general. My main source of information, to learn how to program with Mathematica, has been the fantastic book

Power Programming with Mathematica: The Kernel

However, I would need now to move to do some high performance computing (large matrices diagonalization, mainly) and for this reason I would need some more up-to-date references.

For example: are the PETSc/SLEPc libraries implemented in mathematica?

I was wondering whether you have some suggestion for references about how to do modern HPC with Mathematica.

Thank you!

Comment: "are the PETSc/SLEPc libraries implemented in mathematica?" Certainly not, but you can access them via LibraryLink. That requires some C/C++ programming skill, though.

Comment: good. Where can I learn how to use LibraryLink? the MathLink explanation in Power programming book sounds a bit old fashioned. I know a bit of C/C++.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation on LibraryLink is very brief, but there are some nice examples by developer Arnoud Buzing, e.g. this one: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/189016. At the end of the post, he links to a next one and so on. That should give you already quite a good picture. When you have grasped the main ideas of LibraryLink, you might also be interested in Szabolcs' package [LTemplate](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate); it really helps to automize the writing of a lot of boiler plate code. And he has many and very good tutorials and examples.

Comment: BTW, @HenrikSchumacher , a slightly unrelated question: if I have a very large and sparse matrix,mM, that I want to multiply with a vector, vV, which option do you think is more efficient in time:

1) Dot[mM , vV]

2) (Dot[# , vV] &) /@ mM

3) implement the product with an explicit for cycle and then compile the resulting code? in this last case, is compilation compatible with the sparse input?

Comment: `Dot` should be the method of choice because that will call the appropriate and optimized routine from a suitable library (probably from spBLAS in the Intel MKL). Avoid `Map` at all cost if you opt for best performance. `Compile` does not like `SparseArray`. But of course, you may try to use LibraryLink to call any other method for sparse matrices. I doubt that you find anything faster then `Dot`. Actually, `Dot`ting a sparse matrix by a vector from the right should be the best tuned sparse operation.

Comment: indeed, this is what I was doing. I was checking whether I was forgetting some important speed up! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.